# Is there a Spanish saying that means "to stay true to one's conscience"?

Tags: modismos

Is there a Spanish saying that means "to stay true to one's conscience"? For example, the sentence I want to put it in is "Las protagonistas tienen que desobedecer para sobrevivir y [to stay true to their conscience]".

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an idiom, but a phrase denoting the meaning would be: *mantenerse fiel a los propios principios / a los principios de uno*.

Comment: is "to stay true to one's conscience is completely independent or is part of a cause/effect ?, I don't think the "to" is correct at the beginning, or you have the order wrong : to stay true to one's conscience and survive the protagonists have to disobey" 
or " the protagonists have to disobey to stay true to one's conscience"

Answer (score 3):

As Gustavson comments, the expression you are looking for could as well be "mantenerse fiel a los principios de uno". So your sentence could be:

> Las protagonistas tienen que desobedecer para sobrevivir, manteniéndose fieles a sus principios.

Curiously enough, there is a way to write the whole sentence using an idiom:

> Las protagonistas tienen que hacer objeción de conciencia para sobrevivir.

According to [the dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QmVKx38), "objeción de conciencia" means "refusal to perform acts or services arguing ethical or religious reasons". It was widely used in Spain when the military service was mandatory. You could try to skip the military service by becoming an "objetor de conciencia".

Comment: Es divertido, empiezas hablando en castellano y luego saltas al inglés.

Comment: @fedorqui y lo peor de todo es que lo hago sin darme cuenta...